# Linux sudo, [ant:sshexec] Remote command failed with exit status 127

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, sudo, gradle

A little background:
I have a gradle script that I use in order to install and setup several softwares on many different machines - I run this locally with the purpose to accelerate the deployment process.
The gradle script gets the layer and the server name in as parameters and will install the software by executing a remote ssh linux command (rhel 6).

```
C:\work\source\tools\environment-tools>gradle -Player=service -Pserver=demo1 installSamba
Using libraries from: C:\work\source/lib
:installSamba
Trying to override old definition of datatype scp
Trying to override old definition of datatype sshexec
 --- Executing: yes | yum install samba
 --- failOnError = false, using sudo
 >>>>>
Command: echo 'sudo_pass' | sudo -Ss 'yes | yum install samba'
[sudo] password for root:
/bin/bash: yes | yum install samba: command not found

[ant:sshexec] Remote command failed with exit status 127
```

the command i am trying to execute: simply uses yum to install samba but also triggers a yes in order to automaticaly perform a default samba installation.

The question:
When i execute the script, the following command is remotely executed to install samba:
**echo 'sudo_pass' | sudo -Ss 'yes | yum install samba'**

why would this fail when the following executes perfectly (but with human interaction, i.e. press y and then return):
**echo 'sudo_pass' | sudo -Ss yum install samba**

i imagine i would need to setup the following small gradle installation script correctly: any idea of what i am doing wrong?

```
task installSamba << {
  forAllServers { props ->
    ssh('yes | yum install samba', props)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try the actual option for `yum`, `yum -y install samba`?

Comment: its actually a good idea, but many of the installation commands do not depend on yum. E.g. ssh("echo $password | passwd --stdin bea", props) which would result to the same issue. I currently found an alternative and thats to perform a downgrade of sudo on the remote machine. this will execute the commands flawlessly. But thats not very fruitful. what would be nice is to be able to excute those commands using sudo version 1.7.4p5 instead of having to downgrade to sudo version 1.7.2p2. How could my scripts be changed in order to comply with the newest sudo version?

Answer (score 1):

I later found out that a downgrade of sudo on the remote machine was necessary in order to execute a gradle script like the one above. the downgrade i did was from version: 1.7.4p5 to sudo version 1.7.2p2.
This is a working alternative, but not the best solution. I would rather have the latest sudo update running on the host. The real question then is: how would one go about and fix the above simple script in order for it to execute